# React native navigation replace method not woking

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

I have a screen named `Club` in my stack navigation.

After a particular operation, I am replacing the current 'Club' screen with a new 'Club' screen with different params.

```
navigation.replace('Club',{clubId:'uuu'});
```

The above code successfully pushes a new instance of Club screen on to the stack with the new params. But it fails to replace the previous Club screen.

The navigation stack is as below

```
Home->Club->Club(new params)
```

I want it to be

```
Home-> Club(new params)
```